# flattening json to csv with jqplay

Tags: jq, json-flattener

I'm trying to flatten a json file to .csv.  I'd like to use jqplay for this in stead of programming it in python for example.
The example below is een array that als contains arrays.
My desired output is one line entry on the 2nd array:
so

OPEN, NR1, ....

CLOSED, NR2, ...

....

Can anyone help me with a good jq command for this?

```
[
    {
        "description": "Berendrechtsluis",
        "lock_id": "BES",
        "longitude_wgs84": 4.28561,
        "latitude_wgs84": 51.34414,
        "lock_doors": [
            {
                "state": "OPEN",
                "lock_door_id": "NR1",
                "operational_state": "NO_DATA",
                "state_since_in_utc": "2021-12-29T16:32:23Z",
                "longitude_wgs84": 4.28214,
                "latitude_wgs84": 51.34426
            },
            {
                "state": "CLOSED",
                "lock_door_id": "NR2",
                "operational_state": "WORKING",
                "state_since_in_utc": "2022-01-12T12:32:52Z",
                "operational_state_since_in_utc": "2021-12-22T13:13:57Z",
                "longitude_wgs84": 4.28247,
                "latitude_wgs84": 51.34424
            },
            ....
```

Comment: [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) "is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor", [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/) is a "playground for jq".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sh
jq -r '.[].lock_doors[] | [.[]] | @csv'
```

```
"OPEN","NR1","NO_DATA","2021-12-29T16:32:23Z",4.28214,51.34426
"CLOSED","NR2","WORKING","2022-01-12T12:32:52Z","2021-12-22T13:13:57Z",4.28247,51.34424
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RdkjJUc4dC)

To add column headers, simply prepend them in an array:

```sh
jq -r '["a","b","c"], .[].lock_doors[] | [.[]] | @csv'
```

```
"a","b","c"
"OPEN","NR1","NO_DATA","2021-12-29T16:32:23Z",4.28214,51.34426
"CLOSED","NR2","WORKING","2022-01-12T12:32:52Z","2021-12-22T13:13:57Z",4.28247,51.34424
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1Vblg6pebY)

Comment: Thanks pmf, that answers my question exactly.

Comment: Is there any easy fix to include description on each line? (I know, this goes beyond my initial question).

Comment: @GertVdW Do you mean column headers? Sure, prepend them in an array, see my update.

Comment: I actually mean an extra collum. So: "Berendrechtsluis", "OPEN","NR1","NO_DATA","2021-12-29T16:32:23Z",4.28214,51.34426
"Berendrechtsluis", "CLOSED","NR2","WORKING","2022-01-12T12:32:52Z","2021-12-22T13:13:57Z",4.28247,51.34424,

Comment: @GertVdW Then inject it where the columns are generated: `.[].lock_doors[] | ["Berendrechtsluis", .[]] | @csv`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/d9zxEhsNxa)